# Devise customisation of views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

Is there a way to route devise users to a login and signup screen that doesn't output the header and footer? as everything is being yielded to my application.html.erb

Heres my current code for application.html.erb

```
 <body>
   <div id="wrap">
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
      <%= yield %>
    <div id="push"></div>
   </div>
 <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Controllers support :only and :except options for layouts so you can restrict access in the controller like this:

```
class RandomController < ApplicationController
layout 'application', :except => [:signup, :signin]

def signin
// some code
end

def signup
// some code
end

end
```

I'd recommend you view the official RoR website section ([this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)) on rendering views.

**Update 2**

Set the layout for specific Devise controllers using a callback in config/application.rb.
(so this code belongs in the /config/application.rb file)

This allows for layouts to be specified on a per-controller basis. If, for example, you want a specific layout assigned to Devise::HomeController views:

```
config.to_prepare do
Devise::HomeController.layout "layout_for_home_controller" 
end
```

A more indepth example using four different layouts, one for each controller:

```
config.to_prepare do
Devise::HomeController.layout "layout1"
Devise::UsersController.layout "layout2"
Devise::ArticlesController.layout "layout3"            
Devise::TutorialsController.layout "layout4"        
end
```

Comment: and what if i'm using devise?

Comment: Take a look at this: 

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts

Comment: devise signup and signin are not layouts though. Should I move them   to layouts folder?

Comment: No you need to place the code (update 1) in whichever controller holds the signup and signin methods.. or try the code from update 2 which uses the configuration files.

Comment: should my devise folder be in layouts folder or views folder?

Comment: Not sure to be honest not used device myself. It depends on the contents of the /device/ folder. Does the documentation where you originally got Device from not explain how to implement custom layouts?

Comment: Not at all, but I will continue looking :/

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution, but this is a way of doing it.

```
     <body>
       <div id="wrap">
          <%= render 'layouts/header' unless params[:controller] == "devise/sessions" or "devise/registrations" and params[:action] == "new" %>
          <%= yield %>
        <div id="push"></div>
       </div>
     <%= render 'layouts/footer' unless params[:controller] == "devise/sessions" or "devise/registrations" and params[:action] == "new" %>
     </body>
```

**EDIT:**

application_helper.rb

```
def hidden_header_footer
    params[:controller] == "devise/sessions" or "devise/registrations" and params[:action] == "new"
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= render 'layouts/footer' unless hidden_header_footer %>
<%= render 'layouts/header' unless hidden_header_footer %>
```

Comment: That works! thanks. but i'm sure theres a cleaner way :/

Comment: If this worked for you i would appreciate if you accepted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Devise with the standard layouts, they're render into Main view: <%= yield %>.

So you can change your application.html.erb in:

```
  <body>

   <div id="wrap">

     <% if user_signed_in? %>
       <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
     <% end %>

     <%= yield %>

     <% if user_signed_in? %>
       <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
     <% end %>

   </div>

 </body>
```

And your application_controller.rb in:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  #before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :home]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```